# Use cell Value in Lookup_array, excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an XLOOKUP running to return some date to a cell.  Good stuff.
The problem is that I need the XLOOKUP to be able to search different sheet depending on the value of a cell.  As an example:
`=XLOOKUP(C11,Table_x!C:C,Table_x!B:B,0,0)`

[image]

The x in the Table_x needs to be changed based on the cell value in column B so that it will go to the right table to look up the right value.

Lots of different formats to try and get it to accept the Cell value rather than just characters in the Lookup-array, but it always seems to just take the text entered rather that looking up the cell value.

Comment: Two ways I can think of here. Either using `INDIRECT()` or depending on how your data looks over these lookup sheets, you can use `TOCOL()` to drop all info in one array from all sheets which in contrast to `INDIRECT()` won't be volatile and keep recalculating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `INDIRECT`:

```
=XLOOKUP(C4,INDIRECT("Sheet"&B4&"!C:C"),INDIRECT("Sheet"&B4&"!B:B"),,0)
```

[image]

If data is unique I would suggest to stack it into one sheet to lookup to.

Answer (score 2):

If the data in the sheets you're looking for are unique, you could use TOCOL:

`=XLOOKUP(C5:C6,TOCOL(Sheet2:Sheet32!C1:C99,1),TOCOL(Sheet2:Sheet32!D1:D99,1),"not found")`

This is - as stated in the comments by JvdV - non volatile, as opposed to INDIRECT, which will recalculate if anything(!) in the workbook changes.

[image]